# What does Class<something> mean in Java?

Tags: java

> **This question is an exact duplicate of:**
>   [What does <> (angle brackets) mean in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6607550/what-does-angle-brackets-mean-in-java)

I am reading about `AsyncTask` in Android. I have this example code:

```
private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
     protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
         int count = urls.length;
         long totalSize = 0;
         for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
             totalSize += Downloader.downloadFile(urls[i]);
             publishProgress((int) ((i / (float) count) * 100));
         }
         return totalSize;
     }

     protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
         setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
         showDialog("Downloaded " + result + " bytes");
     }
 }
```

And it is supposed to be called with:

```
new DownloadFilesTask().execute(url1, url2, url3);
```

I can't understand what `<URL, Integer, Long>` means. I have seen them in some other classes like `String<>` but I don't know what is the purpose of them.

Comment: @Aidanc - Hover over downvote button: *Research Effort*. Not only is a dupe, any beginners book on Java covers it as well as the basic tutorials from Oracle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It defines the types of [generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html).

---

For example:

```
List<Integer> list;
```

You declare a variable of class List. But `List` is declared like this, if I'm right:

```
public interface List<T> extends Collection<T>
```

The T is a placeholder for a type that the user of this class can define. In my example, I chose to fill in the T with Integer. In this case it means I'll have a List of Integers.

Answer (score 0):

it is http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/generics.html

but basically what is means is you have some container like

```
List<> aList
```

and the compiler needs to know what type it is holding so you specific the type associated with the container

```
List<String> aList
```