# What is the idea of using `L` in `<L extends SomeClass>` after a class name?

Tags: java, generics

This is a code i found for Egit

I am new to the usage of `PlotCommitList<L extends PlotLane>`.

1. what is the term used for it?
2. what does it signify or mean to the compiler?

`public class PlotCommitList<L extends PlotLane> extends RevCommitList<PlotCommit<L>> {`

Comment: Its called [generic](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html) which introduced in java 1.5.

Comment: It's not a duplicate of that question

Comment: it means that class is 'generic', it can be a pretty big lecture so I suggest you to read a book about it but you can find some information about it [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/)

Comment: @Tichodroma the diamond operator is <> without anything inside - so this question is not a duplicate as it asks about the generic syntax for Java 5+.

Comment: The title shows the diamond operator and the initial question (before all these edits) didn't make it clearer.

Comment: @maba And that's why we have the option of editing and voting to reopen. =)

Comment: @J.Steen Yes but then it should probably be closed with a link to another Java Generic SO question that answers this question.

Comment: This is a possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6607550/what-does-angle-brackets-mean-in-java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The <> operator is used to specify classes in generic templates.

Image a generic "list". In Java up to 1.4, a "list" could only contain generic `Object`s.
If you wanted to make sure you only kept `String`s in your list you had to use a lot of casting and helper methods, which made the code barely readable.

Java 5 introduced generics, which solves the problem - you can create a template class "list of ", and parametrise the class used as parameter or return value.

Furthermore, you can use the `<L extends ...>` and `<L super ...>` to limit the range of classes your template works with, have multiple classes as parameters `<class1,class2>` and combine things up `<class1,class2<class3>>` at will.

There is a very good tutorial at http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/04/java-generics-quick-tutorial.html

Comment: +1 for pointing out what `<L extends ...>` stands for. Thanks for the quick tutorial