# Implementing `Stack` from scratch

Tags: java

I'd like to implement `Stack` from scratch and encountered a problem. I feel like I'm writing the parameters for `push` method wrong such as:

```
public void push(<T> foo){
    myList.add(foo);
}
```

How else can I write the parameter when I'm not sure what type the `foo` is going to be?

```
package Stack;
import java.util.*;

public class Stack<T> {

    private List<T> myList;

    public Stack(){
        myList = null;
    }

    public boolean empty(){
        return (myList == null);
    }

    public void push(<T> foo){
        myList.add(foo);
    }
}
```

Comment: public void push(T foo){
        myList.add(foo);
    }

Remove the angular brackets from around `T`.

Comment: "I feel like I'm writing the parameters for push method wrong" why do you think so? Do you get any error (except obvious NPE since `myList` is `null`)?

Comment: @ChthonicProject, what do the brackets mean in generics?

Comment: @John http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6607550/what-does-angle-brackets-mean-in-java check this.. Might help!

Comment: @John: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6607550/what-does-angle-brackets-mean-in-java

Comment: What is **T. Hanks** doing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public void push(T foo) {
    myList.add(foo);
}
```

You can read more on generics [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/).

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is :

```
public void push(T foo) {
    myList.add(foo);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It just needs to be

```
public void push(T foo){
    myList.add(foo);
}
```

Answer (score -5):

Type cast foo to Object type

```
public void push(Object foo){
    myList.add(foo);
}
```

Comment: Terrible solution. He's using generics. Making push take `Object` just disables the type safety he can get from the generic solution.