# Enumeration<> Enumeration difference

Tags: java, jsp, enumeration

I'm a biginner in JSP and I'm confused about the difference between 
`Enumeration` and `Enumeration<type>`
I'm learning with this Korean book and the example source in it says `Enumeration`
with the eclipse neon version it doesn't work. It works only when it write
`Enumeration<String>`. Can someone tell me the difference?

```
<%@page import="java.util.Enumeration"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; 

charset=UTF-8"pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>헤더 목록 출력</title>
</head>
<body>
<% 
    Enumeration<String> headerEnum = request.getHeaderNames();
    while(headerEnum.hasMoreElements()){
        String headerName = (String)headerEnum.nextElement();
        String headerValue = request.getHeader(headerName);

%>
<%=headerName %> = <%=headerValue %> <br>
<%
    }
%>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does <> (angle brackets) mean in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6607550/what-does-angle-brackets-mean-in-java).

Answer (score 1):

Just give it a look at [the Enumeration documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Enumeration.html). Also review [the generic types documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html).

By using`Enumeration` you are using `Enumeration<Object>` as it is the default. What this `<Object>` does is just indicate the Enumeration class that in that particular instance, the type that it calls E (in the Enumeration Documentation) will be resolved to Object. By using `<String>` happens the same: the type called E will be resolved to String.

If you check the [nextElement() signature](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Enumeration.html#nextElement()) it returns E. So, by using `Enumeration` or `Enumeration<Object>` that method will return Object and you will need the cast you did:

```
 String headerName = (String)headerEnum.nextElement();
```

By using `Enumeration<String>` the method will return an String, so you can directly do this:

```
 String headerName = headerEnum.nextElement();
```