# When a java class extends another class what is the purpose of the <>?

Tags: java, android, class, inheritance

I am working on a tutorial and the example code has the following line:

```
public class GreenAdapter
   extends RecyclerView.Adapter<GreenAdapter.NumberViewHolder> {
```

How does `<GreenAdapter.NumberViewHolder>` fit in, what does the <> syntax mean?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html

Comment: You can take a look at this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6607550/what-does-angle-brackets-mean-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the code it seems you are working in Android.

<> is the syntax for widely used feature in java called **Java Generics** introduced in Java 5.0. They extend Java's type system to allow “a type or method to operate on objects of various types while providing compile-time type safety.”

For an example: if you have had a look at Collections Apis of java, you will find same class with different generics type passed to it. Have a look at ArrayList<> , HashMap<> and other collection apis.

With whatever type you pass , class will start working on that type only and will take care of type safety. So I'll advice you to first go through a very basic tutorial of Java generics before proceeding any further.

Here is the link for very very basic tutorial for Java generics that will clear some air:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_generics.htm

And then if you want to get a deeper understanding of this, read some reference books over this topic. Have a good day :)