# Difference between using angle and square bracket methods in creation of Java Arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I've just recently started with Java and have gotten to Arrays. from what I can tell there are two ways of creating Arrays.

The first method makes the most sense to me coming from a python background.

```
type[] ArrayName;
```

i.e.

```
int[] agesOfParticipants;
```

However a lot of resources online use a different method of creating arrays.

```
ArrayList<ArrayType> Name = new ArrayList<ArrayType>;
```

not only is this different but from what I can tell the term ArrayList is at least partially interchangeable depending on circumstance. For instance in [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38502992/7922708) ArrayList is replaced by class A, which is declared earlier.

```
 A<String> obj=new A<String>();
```

Sorry if this is all basic stuff, but I can't find anywhere that really distinguishes between the two.

Comment: If it helps with your research, the "angle bracket method" is knows as *generics*.

Comment: [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) is **not** an array. It is a `List`, which happens to internally use an array for the implementation, e.g. as compared with `LinkedList`, which uses linked nodes for the implementation. As a `List`, there is functionally no differences between `ArrayList` and `LinkedList`, except for performance and memory characteristics.

Comment: *FYI:* `int[] agesOfParticipants` doesn't *create* an array. It *declares* a variable of type array. The array is created with the `new` operator (or implicitly using an array initializer or when calling a varargs method).

Comment: Adding to the above, you use List when you don't know the size or dynamically you want to add data to it after creating it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In java objects are created using `new` keyword

> creating new `Integer` array with size `10`, array consists of square brackets `[]`

```
Integer[] array = new Integer[10];
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array)); // print array values `[..]`
```

> creating `Integer` object with value 10

```
Integer object = new Integer(10);
System.out.println(object); // print object value 10
```

> creating List that only holds `Integer` values

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(object);
System.out.println(object); // prints list with values [10]
```

> Angular brackets `<>` are Generics, that are used to define homogeneous type of objects (for example list of Integers only)

Comment: but doesn't `Integer[]` also create a homogeneous type of object in that it can only store ints?

Comment: basically arrays are homogeneous objects, `Integer[]` array is also homogeneous that can only store `Integer` objects (not int's), concept call `AutoBoxing` and AutoUnBoxing`, pretty good example https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html

Comment: The question indicates that part of OP's problem is understanding the distinction between an array and an `ArrayList`.  It seems counterproductive to me to describe `ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();` as "... creating Array list that only holds `Integer` values ...".  A person reading this might think that you meant "... creating Array `list` that only holds `Integer` values ...".

Comment: yup updated sir, if it  seems grammatical mistake you are always welcome to edit sir @DawoodibnKareem

Comment: It makes much better sense now, and hopefully won't confuse OP.

Comment: It sounds like OP needs to understand generics.

Comment: do you mean to add more info regarding generics or just provide him reference examples @ChrisRollins

Comment: You're all correct in that I need to work on my terminology. I started Java today and theres a ton of things that are entirely foreign to me. Thank you guys for pointing me in the right directions.