# Unsure how to use <Type> while creating nodes in Linked List

Tags: java, linked-list

I'm learning how to create and use linked lists in Java, but I have stumbled upon a problem that is holding me back. Now, I understand that I need to create Node objects for my items in a linked list, however, the textbook example that I'm using is confusing. Here's the snippet:

```
class Node<Type> {
  Type element;
  Node<Type> next;
  public Node(Type e) {
    element = e;
  }
}
```

What I don't understand is:

1. Why do we use Type data type here?
2. I believe Type is a data type that the programmer has to create themselves (as a public class), is it correct?

I know the `<>` is used to signify an abstract data type, but I'm lost here because I'm used to seeing code like `<String>` or `<Integer>`, but here it's something different.

Also, I wasn't sure how I should address this question so it would be extremely helpful if you could mention the topics I should revise to understand it better.

Comment: I think you should read a tutorial about generics, e.g. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html

Comment: or perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6607550/what-does-t-angle-brackets-mean-in-java?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 0):

1. In Java, when we put something inside <> we are talking about generics, that is, we don't care about the type, which let's us create a Node that can hold a String, an Integer, an Object... any type that you want.

You achieve this 'any type' with generics. If we specified the type of 'element' as 'int', we could only create a LinkedList that holds int's.

The use of the identifier "Type" is up to you. Usually, we use , or, for instance, <K, V> is normally used for a HashMap. This 'identifier' can then be used in the definition of the class to refer to the abstract type, as you can see in the third line:

```
Node<Type> next;
```

2. You can use your own class or any type that comes with Java:

```
Node<Integer> n1 = new Node<Integer>();
Node<MyClass> n2 = new Node<MyClass>();
```